# Assign selected to select box

Tags: jquery, html, select

This is my question.

```
<select class="myselect">
<option value="option 1">option 1</option>
<option value="option 2">option 2</option>
<option value="option 3">option 3</option>
<option value="option 4">option 4</option>
</select>

<div class="mydiv">
<div data-value="option 1">option 1</div>
<div data-value="option 2">option 2</div>
<div data-value="option 3">option 3</div>
<div data-value="option 4">option 4</div>
</div>
```

Second div (mydiv) structure i have generated from jquery. its functioned as a drop down menu. i want to change select box as selected, depend on the selection of "mydive" drop down.

i.e. if i select option 2 in mydiv, in myselect, option 2 should be assigned as selected
(option 2).

how can i implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.mydiv > div').on('click', function(){
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    $('.myselect').val(val);
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqecykmw/)

---

You can use `.data()` method of jQuery to get the `data-value` of clicked `div` and just set the value in the `.myselect`.

---

This could help you understanding it: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqecykmw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mydiv div").click(function(){
   $(".myselect").val($(this).data("value"));
});
```

You can select the option by jquery when mydiv clicked.

Here you go: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3rtzwva/)

---

I had to edit my answer because of `.data()` is more dynamic on appended objects than `.attr()`.
As a nice information I wanted to tell you this.

Have a nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/eLvhsL8x/

```
$('.mydiv div').on('click',function(){
  $('select option[value="'+$(this).attr("data-value")+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
// do smthing on click to div dropdown
$('.mydiv > div').on('click', function (e) {
    // update val of select; get value from data attribute from clicked element
    $('.myselect').val($(this).data('value')).change();
 });
```